# An application created with C # has a thread hang

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio C #, I'm creating an application that records mouse movements through hooking to track mouse movement.

This application works well under normal circumstances, but when the task manager or a particular game is running, the thread stops and the application does not work.
However, when I click the application window again, it tracks mouse movement again.
How do I get this application to work when I'm running Task Manager or a particular game?

```
class Hook
{
    static private DateTime Set_time;

    public static class GlobalMouseHook
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc Ipfn, IntPtr hlnstance, int threadld);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParm);
    }

    public static class MouseHook
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class MouseHookStruct
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public int hwnd;
            public int wHitTestCode;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }
        public const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        public static int hookHandle = 0;
        private static GlobalMouseHook.HookProc callbackDelegate;
        public static void StartHook(DateTime Set_time)
        {
            Hook.Set_time = Set_time;
            callbackDelegate = new GlobalMouseHook.HookProc(CallBack);
            if (hookHandle != 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            hookHandle = GlobalMouseHook.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, callbackDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }
        public static void StopHook()
        {
            GlobalMouseHook.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);
        }
        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }
        public static int CallBack(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            MouseHookStruct mouseInput = (MouseHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseHookStruct));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mouseInput.pt.x + " : " + mouseInput.pt.y);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((MouseMessages)wParam);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now-Set_time);

            return GlobalMouseHook.CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
```

I have attached additional code to use that hooking code.

```
public Form1 ()
{
      Hook.MouseHook.StartHook (DateTime.Now);
      InitializeComponent ();
 }
```

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me, even with Task Manager running in the foreground. You will need to refine your question, narrowing the scenario down better so that you can provide a genuine [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. That said, I'd guess more than likely you're dealing with some other app that is intercepting and inhibiting the mouse messages before your app sees them. With a program that seems to interfere with yours, see if there's any difference between starting your program first vs starting it after the other one.

Comment: Specifically, the application does not work when the game is running in black desert online.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that sharing the name of the game with the SO community is going to help. The odds of someone reading your question having that game installed are low, and the odds of someone installing that game just to see if they can repro your problem are even ower. You claimed in your question that the problem also occurs when Task Manager is running, which is something all of us have installed on Windows, so you should focus on that scenario.

Comment: Is this happening on any game or just that one?

Comment: Is Task Manager only a problem for you when it has `Options > Always on top` ticked?

Comment: Whether check or not, there is a problem.

Comment: How about run as administer

Comment: Run it as run as administer.
Thank you very much for your help.